# How to make an href dynamic using Custom Elements

Tags: javascript, html, href

I wanted to make a header with navs (local website) , and the same header will be repeated in all pages.
So instead of copy pasting it, i made a custom element in js.
The problem is that the hrefs in the main page will be different than the other pages.

This is how it should be in the main page

```
<a href="pages/somepage.html">
```

And this is how it should be in other pages who are in the same folder

```
<a href="somepage.html">
```

Using a custom element will make them all have the same href.

Is there a solution to this or am i missing something really obvious ?
I could just have them all in the same folder but that will get messy the more pages i add.

Comment: have a master layout, that will use one layout on different pages

Answer (score 0):

Make your href absolute by putting a / at the front.

eg

```
<a href="/pages/somepage.html">
```

Comment: But this will make the refrence start from the root (C:/users/me/files/project/pages/somepage.html), can i make it so that all refrences start from the project folder ?

Comment: This is an issue with the way you're viewing the file. You should be viewing this through a url (eg local.project.test/pages/somepage.html). When you put these files on a web host it will be www.project.com/pages/somepage.html.

Comment: I suggest you use laragon, or wamp to host this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you make links following:

```
<a href="/pages/somepage.html">
```

if you add / to front link browser search the folder.